# Room DB - Running insertion into M2M Relation inside Transaction

Tags: android, sql, transactions, android-room

I am inserting a new book into my book table and after trying to assign it to a many-to-many relation table. Imo this should run in a transaction. 
(Because if the m2m insertion fails, the information about the realtionship is lost). My code now looks as follows and fails as i cannot access the `BookUserXRefDao.insert(bookUser);` query due to static context errors.

Is there an easy way to fix this?

```
@Transaction
public void insertBook(Book theBook, List<Integer> userIds){
    long newBookId= insert(theBook);
    //Insert into the m2m relation
    BookUserXRef[] bookUser = new BookUserXRef[userIds.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < userIds.size(); i++) {
        BookUserXRef[i] = new BookUserXRef(newBookId,userIds.get(i));
    }
    BookUserXRefDao.insert(bookUser);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just realized that i can access the Singleton Database Instance from within my transaction.

Therefore i could just use

`AppDb.getAppDb().BookUserXRefDao().insert(bookUser);`

That solved the problem.